# Sub module project is not available for consumers as a dependency - Kotlin Gradle DSL

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

So I have a multi-module project, error-handling.
Where I have a common lib that contains some classes that are used by the lib that I publish, but also I would like to expose that entire lib to the consumers.
This is the structure:

```bash
 Example:
 error-handling-lib                       ## root
    ├── error-handling-common             ## Common lib, compiled to JS/JVM
    │   └─── build.gradle.kts
    │
    ├── error-handling-lib-jvm            ## JVM specific lib 
    │   └── error-handling-lib-ktor       ## KTOR specific - !final! 
    │       │ 
    │       └── build.gradle.kts              ## Build all framework-specific versions
```

error-handling-common has the following `build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    id ("java-library")
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.20"
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "10.2.1"
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint-idea") version "10.2.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // CORE
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktorVersion")

    // TEST DEPENDENCIES
    testImplementation("org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:4.0.0")

    // KOTEST
    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core:$kotestVersion")
    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5:$kotestVersion")
    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-json:$kotestVersion")
    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core:$kotestVersion")
    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-json:$kotestVersion")
    testImplementation("io.kotest.extensions:kotest-assertions-ktor:$kotestKtorAssertionVersion")
    testImplementation("io.kotest.extensions:kotest-extensions-koin:$kotestKoinExtVersion")
}

tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
        freeCompilerArgs += "-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
    }
}
```

error-handling-lib-ktor

```
plugins {
    id("java-library")
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.20"
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "10.2.1"
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint-idea") version "10.2.1"
    id("maven-publish")
    id("com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin") version "2.1.5"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri("artifactregistry://......./maven-app-libraries")
    }
}

dependencies {
    // CORE
    api(project(":error-handling-common"))
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-auto-head-response:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-status-pages:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-cors:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-call-logging:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktorVersion")

    // TESTS
    testImplementation("io.insert-koin:koin-test:$koinVersion")
    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktorVersion")
    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-tests:$ktorVersion")
    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-test-host:$ktorVersion")

    // TEST DEPENDENCIES
    testImplementation("org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:4.0.0")

    // KOTEST
    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core:$kotestVersion")
    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5:$kotestVersion")
    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-json:$kotestVersion")
    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core:$kotestVersion")
    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-json:$kotestVersion")
    testImplementation("io.kotest.extensions:kotest-assertions-ktor:$kotestKtorAssertionVersion")
    testImplementation("io.kotest.extensions:kotest-extensions-koin:$kotestKoinExtVersion")
}

tasks.getByName<Test>("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
        freeCompilerArgs += "-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
    }
}
```

Unfortunately with the API dependency, I'm not getting the job done.
Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I am sorry, but I think the question is not clear about exactly what you need. Can you rephrase the question with correct references to which library should be exposed to consumers?

Answer (score 0):

`api(project(...))` is not sufficient, you also need to actually publish that other project.

`api` just means that consumers won't need to *explicitly* add a dependency on that other module, but it still needs to exist in the maven repository.

Another option would be to manually add all the compiled files from the common module into the library's jar, but that is hacky and shouldn't be necessary if you just publish the common module independently.